# "I feel well" vs "I feel good"?

Tags: grammar

"I feel well" and "I feel good" these both sentences are used occasionally, but what is difference between them. I mean when someone ask to a patient "How are you feeling now" and he replies "I feel well" or "I feel good" then the person who is asking this question might be confused. I mean in which context patient is informing.
Thanks...

Comment: This question has answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155395/is-it-im-feeling-good-or-im-feeling-well) in English stackexchange site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know that after "feel" we need to use adjectives, not adverbs, don't you? For example, I feel *ill*, *cheerful*, *bad*, etc.

So, if *well* is an adjective, then it means *healthy*: I feel well = My health is good.

And if you feel *good*, then you feel *happy* ("I feel good! And I feel nice, like sugar and spice!" - from [James Brown's "I feel good"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuDeBcpLITQ)).

However, *good* can also mean *healthy* depending on the context:

> I don't feel very good. I need to lie down.

In this case *good* and *well* are interchangeable.

Comment: Some prescriptivists would argue that "I feel good" would mean that the speaker does not feel evil at the moment.

Comment: As a Briton, when I say "How are you?" to an American, and he/she says "I'm good", I want to say "I wasn't enquiring about your moral status".

Comment: I should perhaps modify my comment to read "to an American, or a British millennial".